# Scanner is requiring me to type inputs twice just for one to register

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I've been doing a ton of research on this for the past few hours, with no luck. I am pretty sure this is a problem with .next() or .nextLine() (according to my searches). However, nothing has helped me solve my problem.

When I run the code below, I have to type in input twice, and only one of the inputs is subsequently added to the arrayList (which can be seen when you print the contents of the arrayList).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester{


public static void main(String[] args) {
    AddStrings();
}

public static void AddStrings() {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(); //this arraylist will hold the inputs the user types in in the while loop below

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Input file name (no spaces) (type done to finish): ");
        if(console.next().equals("done")) break;

        //console.nextLine(); /*according to my observations, with every use of .next() or .nextLine(), I am required to type in the same input one more time
        //* however, all my google/stackoverflow/ reddit searches said to include 
        //* a .nextLine() */
        //String inputs = console.next(); //.next makes me type input twice, .nextLine only makes me do it once, but doesn't add anything to arrayList
        strings.add(console.next());


    }
    System.out.println(strings); //for testing purposes

    console.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your code is that you are doing console.next() two times. 
*1st Inside if condition and 
2nd while adding to **ArrayList**.*
 Correct Code :

```
public class TestClass{
public static void main(String[] args) {
  AddStrings();
}

public static void AddStrings() {
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(); //this arraylist will hold the inputs the user types in in the while loop below

while(true) {
    System.out.println("Input file name (no spaces) (type done to finish): ");
    String input = console.next();
    if(input.equals("done")) break;
    strings.add(input);

    System.out.println(strings);
}
System.out.println(strings); //for testing purposes

console.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are asking for two words to be inserted. Just remove one of them.

Use it this way:

```
String choice = console.next();
if (choince.equals('done')) break;
strings.add(choice);
```